# Flask-WTF forcing to fill all the fields even tho they're not rendered in the template

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to send the data to the current URL with post method, but "FinalForm" is failing validation because not all the fields are filled when I've only rendered two fields into the template from the form. Is there any way to overcome this?

```
#...
class MotherboardForm(FlaskForm):
    chipset_model = StringField("ჩიპსეტი", validators=[DataRequired()])
    socket_type = StringField("სოკეტი", validators=[DataRequired()])
    ram_technology = StringField("მეხსიერების ტიპი", validators=[DataRequired()])


class RamForm(FlaskForm):
    frequency = StringField("სიხშირე", validators=[DataRequired()])
    size = StringField("მეხსიერების მოცულობა", validators=[DataRequired()])


class FinalForm(ItemForm, BasicsForm, CpuForm, GpuForm, MotherboardForm, RamForm):
    submit = SubmitField("done")
```

In html I'm only rendering these fields

```
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>

{{ form.hidden_tag() }}

{{ form.frequency.label }}
{{ form.frequency() }}

{{ form.size.label }}
{{ form.size() }}

{{ form.submit() }}

</form>
```

This is the view function:

```
@app.route("/list_item", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def list_item():
    item = FinalForm()

    if item.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for("list_cpu"))

    return render_template("add_item.html", form=item)
```

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If a field is set with validator `DataRequired`, it will always asks for input whether the field is rendered or not. The option would be to remove `DataRequired` validator or if the error still arise, use `Optional` validator.

Or you could fill the formdata with dummy value before validating it.